# material-ui dialog causes react-hook-form to change isValid value causing RTL act errors

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I am trying to test a dialog with react testing library. This dialog contains a form I render with react hook form. This form has a single field with some validation on it. When the component renders, `isValid` flips from false to true to false again. This causes issues with react testing library as it detects changes and complains about `act`.

I have created a small sandbox to demonstrate my issue here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-chaum-pmgozq?file=/src/App.tsx

See how `isValid` goes from false to true to false again in the console.

Now, remove the wrapping `Dialog` and watch it work as intended, sticking at false.

However, it seems to be a combination of both Dialog and react-hook-forms proxy of `isValid`. If I remove all references to `isValid`, then the form renders only once.

I am not sure how I can get around this or what the right approach is. I would like to test the entire dialog, as KCD always says to test as close to the user experience as possible, so I don't think extracting the form and testing that is a good idea. In the same breath, im not even sure how to utilise `waitFor` to get around the issue.

Comment: Did some tests, if you remove the form part the isValid goes from false and then true. So I guess the behavior is that it defaults to false, dialog is not rendered at first, so it goes to true and after the form is rendered it goes back to false. waitFor could be an option I think, you just need to use await waitFor(()=>expect something), then you can do you tests after. waiFors should have only one expectation and because it is async, the it, or test should have the async descriptor also.

Comment: It was an option, but it felt hacky and I wasn't sure what to even expect.

Comment: I have made the test stop complaining by replacing a single `getBy` with `findBy`. This is ofcourse not ideal as it's a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I think an alternative approach of writing code will help in this scenario.

I have extracted your `form` and all logic related to `react-hook-form` in a new component called `MyForm` and then I rendered `MyForm` inside `Dialog` component.

Now I can see only 1 `log` in the console.

Here is the link of changed codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-frog-cjpi3h?file=/src/App.tsx